Payment Plans & comparison of optimization solvers
Do any of you have experience to share with me how startups that address practical problems provide licenses for optimization software such as Gurobi, CPLEX, and XPress to their customers?
Specifically, do you opt for monthly or annual subscriptions that allow customers to use the software while solving their models, or are there alternatives like a "pay-per-solve" model? Additionally, are there variations in pricing or are there companies that offer more flexible approaches during negotiations?
I am completely new to commercializing inside the Operations Research Realm.

Easiest answer is to ring these commercial companies and let Sales explain all the options.

At Mosek we post prices online, see https://www.mosek.com/sales/commercial-pricing/. However, for volume and OEM sales, a special deal is usually negotiated. So I agree with Riley.

Generally speaking there are two common pricing models (besides free open source):

Pay per CPU core (or server node)
Pay per unique resource being solved per month (vehicle in VRP, employee in shift scheduling, etc) regardless of the number of runs.

Alternative models are hard to build a viable business model around:

Pay per solve run: Large datasets are far more difficult to solve than small datasets. Prohibits a customer to do Real-time Planning (resolve the datset multiple times per day).
Pay per solve minute: incentives the solver vendor to build a slow solver.
Pay per model: Some models are build in a few hours, others take half a year. Doesn't scale with the size of the datasets, so it would be crazy expensive for small customers but crazy cheap for large customers.

Besides that, there's also pay for support, but that got us almost killed despite having a wildly successful project (15k downloads per month).
Your mileage may vary. There is no single truth in pricing, but it is a complex art to come with something that is a win-win for the (potential) customers and the vendor, regardless of the size of the customer.
